# Php with Facebook SDK don't load page

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I use this code to take information about people friends with Facebook
:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

$app_id = 'xxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxx';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
try {

$user_profile = $facebook->api('me/friends');
print_r($user_profile);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
} else {
$params = array(
'scope' => 'user_birthday',
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>");
}
?>
```

But now, a lot of time, when i try to load this , i see that in the url the param "code" start to change a lot of time and the page don't load. What kind of problem is that?

Comment: is php showing any error or warning

Comment: No, the page become blank and the url start to show different code parameter every second! I don't know. Sometimes it work if i delete my cookie.

Comment: Please check the answer by Bass Jobsen and update if you still face the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`$user` is false in your code for some reason (always). May be the facebook user didn't accept your app.  `$facebook->getLoginUrl($params);` redirects to the request uri, with `$user` false  the request uri redirects to `$loginUrl`. This cause an endless loop.